# How to insert documents in Package.XML

Tags: xml, package.xml, manifest

How do you correctly insert documents (more specifically images in a document) in the package.xml manifest.

Scenario: I am trying to create an unlocked package and with that package, I would like to insert my company's logo so that I can reference that image onto custom tabs.

Below is what I have declared. When I retrieve it from the org, I see the document in scope populate but when I go to create the package I get the following error *(the folder logo does not exist)*

Is my sytax correct? The folder is called Logo and the image is called Logo.

```
<types>
   <members>Logo</members>
   <members>Logo/Logo.jpg</members>
   <name>Document</name>
```

[image]

Comment: I think the package manifest is correct, but you would need to have your Logo folder metadata (file that would end in -meta.xml and contain the metadata for that folder) in your documents folder. Did the folder download when you performed the retrieve?

Comment: @PhilHawthorn I believe with the attached image I just edited the OP with shows that it was retrieved correctly. It is just weird that when I go to create the package, I get the error.

Appreciate your feedback!

Comment: That folder looks to be is sfdx format, whereas I _think_ you're trying to deploy in metadata format? If that is the case, i think the folder metadata file would be `Logo-meta.xml`. If you want to deploy as-is, use `sfdx force:source:deploy` (you don't then need package.xml)

Answer (score 1):

This is what ended up working for me after a bit of trial and error.

**folder structure**
(make sure `Logo-meta.xml` is inside documents directory and `Logo.jpg-meta.xml` is inside the Logo directory)

```
package.xml
documents/
 | 
 | -- Logo-meta.xml
 | -- Logo/
      | -- Logo.jpg
      | -- Logo.jpg-meta.xml
```

**package.xml**

```
<types>
   <members>Logo</members>
   <members>Logo/Logo.jpg</members>
   <name>Document</name>
</types>
```

**Logo-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DocumentFolder xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <accessType>Public</accessType>
    <name>Logo</name>
    <publicFolderAccess>ReadOnly</publicFolderAccess>
</DocumentFolder>
```

**Logo/Logo.jpg-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <name>Logo</name>
    <internalUseOnly>true</internalUseOnly>
    <public>false</public>
</Document>
```

Comment: Are you saying that I have to creates two additional XML files and then add them to under where my Package.XML file lives locally? Appreciate the help!

Comment: yes you have to create 2 xml files.. one lies within `documents` folder and the other lies within `documents/logo` folder 

@andrew

Comment: I have updated the folder structure in the answer to make it clearer